Konx API - Get MDM Devices - Pagination
I'm looking to retrieve a list of MDM devices via the Knox API. I'm curious about implementing pagination to gather all devices through API calls. The documentation mentions the presence of 'limit' and 'start' attributes. Could you provide guidance on how to incorporate these attributes into the API call effectively?
enter image description here
I attempted to retrieve the device list and received 800 devices. According to the documentation, the default limit is set to 1000 devices. However, I'm uncertain if there are more than 1000 devices. How can I fetch additional devices beyond this limit?
